# Why aren't I getting a 404 with an unhandled state?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, route-provider

I am using $stateProvider to set-up my states like so:

```
constructor($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state("something", {
            url: "/index.html"
        })
       // many more
}
```

I am not using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('default-something');`, so when I type `/invalidstate`, I was expecting a 404. Instead, I'm getting a 200 response.

What I'm trying to do is set up a 404 interceptor, but in order for me to intercept, I have to get a 404. I can't fathom for the life of me why a state that's not handled would result in a 200.

Comment: You can't, from the client, cause the server to give you a 404. If you want the server to give a 404 on routes that don't exist, the server would need to be aware of what routes do exist.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down-vote? Hopefully it's not because I misunderstood something, because that's the whole point of the site.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. I was thinking the server would not recognize it as a valid route and I _would_ be getting a 404 for some reason. Chalk it up to my noobishness with angular routing.

Comment: the server isn't reading your angujar.js code, so it has no way of knowing what routes are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a 200 response because so far as the server is concerned, that is a valid route.